# Transmitting problems in Altbeacons from android to Ios device

Tags: android

```
Beacon beacon = new Beacon.Builder()
        .setId1("XYZ MY UUID") // UUID for beacon
        .setId2("1") // Major for beacon
        .setId3("5") // Minor for beacon
        .setManufacturer(0x004C) // Radius Networks.0x0118  Change this for other beacon layouts//0x004C for iPhone
        .setTxPower(-56) // Power in dB
        .setDataFields(Arrays.asList(new Long[] {0l})) // Remove this for beacon layouts without d: fields
        .build();

BeaconParser beaconParser = new BeaconParser()
        .setBeaconLayout("m:2-3=0215,i:4-19,i:20-21,i:22-23,p:24-24");

BeaconTransmitter beaconTransmitter = new BeaconTransmitter(getApplicationContext(), beaconParser);
beaconTransmitter.startAdvertising(beacon, new AdvertiseCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onStartFailure(int errorCode) {
        Log.e("TAG", "Advertisement start failed with code: " + errorCode);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartSuccess(AdvertiseSettings settingsInEffect) {
        Log.i("TAG", "Advertisement start succeeded.");
    }
});
```

hello guys, i am using this code in android for transmit beacons and using ios device for detect or receive advertisement. but in my ios device, i am not getting any notification. is there any mistake in my code ? please help... i am using AltBeacon library for that.